# Установка ssl сертификат на Vesta (Не работает https)

Tags: http, ssl, https, домен, сертификат

В vesta добавил все данные для ssl, файлы с расширением ssl создал, но не работает https. Домен zizli.ru. Все как по гайду (https://web-panda.ru/post/deploy-nodejs-vestacp), кроме домена и порта (там указаны свои). Http работает, приложение на nextJS. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем дело.

Answer (score 0):

В этой заметке вообще нет упоминания о сертификатах. Как вы его добавили в конфигурацию nginx?

Добавление HTTPS в nginx выглядит вот так:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  server_name your.server.domain;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }

  # Приватный ключ и сертификат
  ssl_certificate     /var/www/certs/your.site.domain/chain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /var/www/certs/your.site.domain/privkey.pem;
}

# Редирект с HTTP на HTTPS
server {
 listen 80;
 return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```